# Processamento de frame pós-processamento em janelas

Tags: python, filter, display

É possível processar o frame da tela no Windows?

Estou tentando fazer um filtro / compressor de cores da tela opensource em python.

Comment: Amigo, você respondeu uma pergunta em **Português** porque não traduz sua pergunta, já que sabe que a **comunidade é em Português**? Também faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona a **comunidade**.

Comment: Sim @wmsouza, achei que estivesse na versão em ingles, perdão e obrigado pelo edit.

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais prática de ter screenshots é com o pacote "pyautogui".

Basta instalar o pyautogui no seu ambiente Python e então:

```
import pyautogui
image = pyautogui.screenshot()
```

Isso devolve um objeto imagem compatível com a PIL, que é mais ou menos o padrão para lidar com imagens em Python.

Note que pelo menos no Linux, essa funcionalidade depende da instalação de um pacote não relacionado com Python chamado "scrot" - em Debian e Ubunut, instale com "sudo apt-get install scrot". No Fedora e RedHat: "sudo dnf install scrot".